# Browse images on a server from a form button like when uploading an image

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am very new to Laravel so this may be a trivial one but basically, in a form, I want a choose image button that then allows the user to browse a selection of images from my image storage (s3).

I want them to be able to browse it in the same way as if they were doing a file upload.... but restrict their visibility to being a directory containing all the images on my server, so I guess basically allowing them to browse a directory on the server via windows explorer or finder so they can select an already existing image.

Is that doable? easily?

On my website I have an image section where users can upload images, then in another section I have a form and part of the form allows a user to select one of the uploaded images.

It doesn't matter who uploaded the image, all users should have access to this image bank to choose one for the form.

Any help, advice or a nudge in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

Many thanks,

Krivvenz.

Comment: Sound you want something like this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WlLrDx_ZVw4

Comment: Looking at the video that does look like exactly what I need! I shall read up on Elfinder and TinyMCE as I have never heard of either of them. I guess there is no easy in built Laravel sort of solution? Thanks for the advice Lewis.